# Sencha command not found in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I want to create a project using Sencha touch. My OS is Ubuntu. I installed Sencha in Ubuntu,  downloaded `sencha-touch-2.1.0-gpl` and extracted it. I followed instructions in the documentation using terminal with the following code:

```
sencha generate app GS ../GS
```

But I  got  an error message:

```
sencha: command not found
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT]

Sencha has released new version of SDK tools and they are now calling it "Sencha CMD"(Not sure why). For Sencha Touch 2.1* you will need to uninstall old sencha SDK tools and install Sencha CMD. It can be downloaded from here: http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download

Old Sencha SDK tools requires "command" directory inside sdk folder but from 2.1.0 that folder is not available. For more details about new CMD please refer http://www.sencha.com/blog/all-new-sencha-cmd/

[/EDIT]

[OBSOLETE]

You need to install SDK tools also, so please go to http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools/download and install correct(Check OS & Bit) Sencha SDK tools. Once installation is successful you should be able to run the command from terminal.

[/OBSOLETE]

Answer (score 1):

[Sencha Command docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/command):

> ### **Command Not Found**
>
> Upon running sencha, if there is an error message appears saying "sencha: command not found" on OS X / Linux or
>   "'sencha' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file." on Windows, follow these steps to
>   troubleshoot:
>
> - Close all existing terminal / command prompt windows and re-open them.
> - Make sure that Sencha SDK Tools is properly installed:
>
>   - The installation directory exists. By default, the installation path is
>       */Applications/SenchaSDKTools-{version}* on OS X,
>       */opt/SenchaSDKTools-{version}* on Linux, and *C:\Program
>       Files\SenchaSDKTools-{version}* on Windows.
>   - The path to SDK Tools directory is
>       prepended to your system's PATH environment variable. From the
>       terminal, run ***echo $PATH*** (*echo %PATH%* on Windows). The SDK Tools
>       directory should be displayed in part of the output. If this is not
>       the case, add it to your PATH manually.
>   - The environment variable
>       *SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_{version}* is set, with the value being the absolute
>       path to the installation directory mentioned above. For example: If
>       the installed version is '2.0.0-beta2', a *SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA2*
>       must be set. From the terminal, run *echo $SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA2*
>       (*echo %SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA2%* on Windows). If the output is
>       empty, set the environment variable manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
http://www.icodeya.com/2012/12/installing-sencha-touch-201-on-ubuntu.html

I was able to make mine work perfectly. You need to add permission to sencha. and make sure that sencha CMD created a path inside your .bashrc then
Follow Step 4 , "`sudo chown -R yourUsername:www-data sencha-touch-2.0.1-gpl`"

Answer (score 1):

This link works perfectly: [how to setup sencha in ubuntu](http://www.icodeya.com/2012/12/installing-sencha-touch-201-on-ubuntu.html)

Or

Just run senchacmd package file which is download from [sencha for linux](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) and check **.bashrc** file, either logout or restart system or best way is to use "source" command e.g `source .bashrc` (**update: run command where your .bashrc file is located**, normally it would be located in home/username/.bashrc). After this point your cursor to sencha sdk directory or go through terminal and type `sencha generate app app_name ../app_name` that's it, you are done!!

Answer (score 1):

I used some time and made a little tutorial for this, maybe it works for you, best regards, Victor

http://victorbarzana.blogspot.de/2013/05/how-to-install-senchasdktools-200-beta3.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.